# lg g820n can't get into fastboot/bootloader

Tags: android, bootloader, lg, fastboot

I have a LG G8(LM-G820N, android 12) on which I am trying to get it into the bootloader but am unable to do so, even though I have been able to do so previously.

1. I tried volume up + power button
   just does a normal reboot
2. I tried "adb reboot bootloader"
   just does a normal reboot
3. I tried holding the volume down & plugging the USB in
   normal reboot; occasionally brings me to a black battery charging screen

- The device is already rooted & bootloader is unlocked.
- I have proper driver settings on my PC.
- I tried another PC & USB port, but none of them worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. Posting for someone who has problem like this,
you need engineered abl file in order to get into bootloader!!

[rooting guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-lg-g8-g8x-v50-bootloader-unlock-and-magisk-root-using-firehose.4221793/)
follow the bootloader unlock steps